# Can you have a subview in a subview? swift 3

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, swift3, subview

Is it possible to have subviews in a UIView which is already displayed as a subview?

In my main view controller I have a UIView which shows as a subview on a tapped marker call. I want to put a further subview into that presented subview. Is it possible and how is that done?

Comment: You mean you want to insert subviews into a map pin callout view? A picture tells a thousand word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any `UIView` class can have subviews. Subview is not a type of object. The type is still `UIView`.

*How is this done?*

Same exact way as any other `UIView` object. Simply add subview. Treat it equally:

```
let mainView = self.view
let subview = mainView.viewWithTag(42)

let newSubview = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 10))
subview?.addSubview(newSubview)
```

Comment: this is so useful, only had to change one word! I had 'self.view.addSubview' in my main view controller but as you pointed out i should have had 'self.subview.addSubview...'. it makes so much sense now!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, subviews can be nested. An example playground:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let view_1 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
view_1.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

let view_2 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 100))
view_2.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
view_1.addSubview(view_2)

let view_3 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 50, height: 50))
view_3.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
view_2.addSubview(view_3)


PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view_1
```